# One way synchronization two folders

Tags: c#, directory

I have one folder called `OLD`. There is a directory structure inside it like:

```
Old  
---DSL  
---------CI  
------------AppFolder1    
------------AppFolder2  
---------------------------FUN2    
--------CA  
------------AppFolder1
```

Inside each folder there may or may not be files.

I have one folder called `NEW`, which has the updates and the depending upon the changes appropriate directory structure is inside it. The point is that it will be same as `OLD`. For example:

```
NEW  
---DSL  
---------CI  
------------AppFolder2  
---------------------------FUN2  
--------CA
```

As you can see the directory structure (including folder names) as same. I want all files in `NEW` to replace appropriate files in `OLD`.

Please provide me a starting point for it.

Comment: Have a look at the rsync algorithm

Comment: Check out the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992.aspx)

Comment: What if there are folders or files in new that are not in old or vice-versa?

Comment: @TimSchmelter NEW will be a subset of OLD. There is just no condition in which there is a folder in NEW which is not in OLD. And it is a one way sync, files will never be copied from OLD to NEW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a folder `Old` with the structure:

Old Root `C:\Old` for example.

```
-Old
--CI
---AppFolder1
---AppFolder2
```

And `New` which had nothing in it.

Then ran the console app I made setting the `NewRoot` to `C:\New` and got:

```
-New
--CI
---AppFolder1
---AppFolder2
```

Not sure if this is the sort of thing you were looking for - if not advise what you want to be done differently :)

```
private static void SyncDirectories(string oldRoot, string newRoot)
{
  CreateDirectoriesRecursive(Directory.GetDirectories(oldRoot), newRoot);
}
private static void CreateDirectoriesRecursive(string[] oldDirectories, string root)
{
  foreach (string oldDirectory in oldDirectories)
  {
    string directoryToCreate = root + @"\" + new DirectoryInfo(oldDirectory).Name;
    if (!Directory.Exists(directoryToCreate))
      Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryToCreate);
    if (Directory.GetDirectories(oldDirectory).Count() > 0)
      CreateDirectoriesRecursive(Directory.GetDirectories(oldDirectory), directoryToCreate);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class for controlling changes in the OLD directory to repeat them into the NEW one.

Also, you can place this watch on the NEW too, for managing unwanted access there.